# Fatal error in my website

Tags: magento-1.8

I am getting a fatal error on my website. I am using magento 1.8 version. Can anybody let me know what is the cause of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a new magento installation or installing already running site?

It's look like it is a already running site,which you are unable to configure on your machine or server.

There are some module in community codepool which are causing problem. You have to check the site after disabling them.

There may be a possibility that compilation mode is on. You have to check this, if it is on then disable it.

To disable compilation 
Go to root folder includes/config.php
 and comment every thing. clear cache and the try to run you store by hitting home page URL.

Comment: This is already a running website. Can you let me know the path to go to the config page as I am not a developer.

Comment: It is in /home/diamofft/public_html/includes/config.php. comment everything inside it.

Comment: What do you mean by saying comment everything inside it ??

Comment: check that these two line are commented or not.
define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');

define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');

Comment: Check this also.

Please check if you have a folder named "errors" on your magento root (in /home/diamofft/public_html/) and whether there is a php file named report.php (probably someone had added entire errors folder to the gitignore or something?

Comment: So...do I need to delete the error folder ??